# Prepared statement error when trying to receive password from DB

Tags: java, mysql, prepared-statement

I get an error in this method:

```
public String databaseServer(String email)throws IllegalArgumentException {
    Connection dbCon = null;
    Statement stmt = null;
    String password = null;

    System.out.print(email);
    String query = "SELECT password FROM user WHERE email = ?";

    try {
        dbCon = initializeDBConnection(); 
        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = dbCon.prepareStatement(query);
        preparedStatement.setString(1, email);
        ResultSet rs = preparedStatement.executeQuery(query);
        while (rs.next()) {
            password = rs.getString("password");    
        }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Collection.class.getName())
           .log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } 
    //close connection ,stmt and resultset here       
    return password;
}
```

The error is:

> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?' at line 1

I've checked the connection and the incoming string and they both work fine.

Anybody knows what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of

```
ResultSet rs = preparedStatement.executeQuery(query);
```

do

```
ResultSet rs = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
```

Comment: Thank you good sir! (I will mark the answer as correct in 11 minutes)